# ColdFusion Modulus Function returning incorrect value

Tags: coldfusion, modulus

I have recently written some code which schedules messages to send to one of our SMTP servers. This data is stored in an MySQL database. The algorithm schedules messages based on an hourly limit. Here is a portion of the algorithm, which is within a loop to schedule as many messages as required.

```
<cfif hourlyLimit lte 60>
    <cfset minutesPerMail = 60 / hourlyLimit>
    <cfset minutesAdd = int(minutesPerMail)>
    <cfset secondsAdd = round((minutesPerMail % 1) * 60)>
    <cfset queueDate = #DateAdd('n', minutesAdd, queueDate)#>
    <cfset queueDate = #DateAdd('s', secondsAdd, queueDate)#>
```

For debugging purposes, I appended the following code to this portion...

```
<cfdump var="#minutesPerMail#"> (Outputs 1.421857...)
<cfdump var="#secondsAdd#"> (Outputs 0)
```

I originally suspect there may be a rounding error, and as such, I then added the following code...

```
<cfset modTest = minutesPerMail % 1>
<cfdump var="#modTest#"> (Outputs 0)
```

As you can see, by the use of the modTest variable, the modulus function is not working appropriately, as the proper output would be .421857... .

EDIT/SOLUTION: Performing a modulus action within ColdFusion returns an integer, not a float, and thus will automatically round the element to zero.

Comment: That is the expected result. "[MOD] does
integer arithmetic and ignores fractional parts." http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7ffa.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just change it to this:

```
<cfset secondsAdd = minutesPerMail - minutesAdd>
```

Comment: Yeah, in this example it works. I performed some research and determined that the modulus operator returns an integer and not a float, for whatever reason..

Answer (score -1):

To explain MOD slightly further, it returns either a remainder or 0. Think of it as TRUE or FALSE so that if it returns TRUE, it has a remainder, but if it returns FALSE, it does not have a remainder. Hope this helps to clarify why it returns an integer and not a float.

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted, as it is incorrect. CF's `MOD` does use integer arithmetic, but the returned remainder is *not* always 0 or 1. Example, 9 mod 5 = 4

Comment: You are correct. I should have stated that it can be treated like it returns either TRUE or FALSE instead of saying 1 or 0. I didn't word my response the best but that was what I meant.

Comment: I have edited the comment accordingly - thanks for your feedback.